# Don't print char when using getch() ncurses

Tags: input, ncurses

I need to get a char with ncurses, but when I get the char, I don't want it printed to the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `C`, you can use `noecho();`.

The following is a relevant excerpt from the manual pages.

> The `echo` and `noecho` routines control whether characters typed by the user are echoed by `getch` as they are typed. Echoing by the tty driver is always disabled, but initially `getch` is in echo mode, so characters typed are echoed. Authors of most interactive programs prefer to do their own echoing in a controlled area of the screen, or not to echo at all, so they disable echoing by calling `noecho`.